# Close application when input window is closed and return to start if input is empty or doesn't correspond to value

Tags: powershell

I wrote a small program, but it has a slight issue. The user is supposed to input a value, which corresponds to a number. The problem with the code is that whenever you enter nothing at all, enter a value hat doesn't exist or close the input window, it still runs the code following it.

```
$A = 87
$B = 130
$C = 80
$D = 83
$E = 78
$F = 92
 
$input = $(
      Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
      [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Select a computer','Test', 'row/column')
     )

 

  if($input -eq 'E2')
 {
     Set-Variable -Name "ip" -Value $A
 }
 
  if($input -eq 'A2')
  {
   
    Set-Variable -Name "ip" -Value $B 
  }
  
  if($input -eq 'D3')
  {
   
    Set-Variable -Name "ip" -Value $C 
  }
  
  if($input -eq 'C3')
  {
   
    Set-Variable -Name "ip" -Value $D 
  }
  
  if($input -eq 'E4')
  {
     Set-Variable -Name "ip" -Value $E
  }
  
  if($input -eq 'F4')
 {
     Set-Variable -Name "ip" -Value $F
 }
   
#remaining code#
```

I'd like the application to close when I X out of the input window & return to the beginning of the script if a wrong value or none is entered at all, but I'm new to PowerShell and can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Have a look at the [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch) and [`do .. while/until`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_do) statements. Last but not least, since you're basically mapping one value to another in this instance, you may also want to look at [hash tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables) (`@{ "E2" = 87, "A2" = 130, ... }[$input]`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Jeroen Mosterd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72290287/close-application-when-input-window-is-closed-and-return-to-start-if-input-is-em#comment127714349_72290287) commented, you can make this much easier using a Hashtable with corresponding Name/Values instead of using separate variables.

Also, don't use a variable called `$input` because that is a [Automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#input) in PowerShell

Try something like this:

```
$hash = @{
    E2 = 87
    A2 = 130
    D3 = 80
    C3 = 83
    E4 = 78
    F4 = 92
}

Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic

do {
    $ip = $null
    $choice = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Type the name of a computer','Test')
    # exit the loop if the user cancels the box or clicks OK with an emty value
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($choice)) { break }

    $ip = $hash[$choice]
} until ($ip)


if (!$ip) { exit }

# remaining code#
```

Comment: how do I do that? I'm new to stack overflow.